# Any alternative to user_groups permission ?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on a facebook canvas app that needs user_groups permission.But It Seems like user_groups permission is no longer available.I am searching for an alternative to that permission scope. 
My app idea:

group admins can post questions/survey and members can ans those via app
if a user is the member of specific groups He can ans those questions. **i dont need to post on groups on behalf of users.**

How can i implement it without user_groups permission?

I have an (not so efficient) idea that, when admin access the app get the list of group members. when users access the app match them against the list.

But the problem is there can be a huge amount of members and I need to check and get the list every time when admin enters.

I am open to any idea to make it efficient. thanks :)

Comment: All you can get access to now is the list of groups the user is an admin of, using the `user_managed_groups` permission. There is no way to specifically find out if a user is a member of a group, besides looping through the results of `/group-id/members`

Comment: @CBroe problem is my group has more than 100k members :(